# Flag values in dataframe based on condition at time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to flag some values based on the below condition:

Condition: if the temperature does not change by 0.1 degree C within 60 minutes, flag the values or print the indices of the values.

I am not able to code this efficiently and the code that I have is giving me an error.Can someone please provide suggestions?

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename')

df['Datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime']) 
df = df.set_index(['Datetime'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
       if (row['temperature(C)'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min',base=0, label='right')).diff() < 0.1):
       print index, row ['temperature(C)']

Error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

sample data:

[image]

Comment: Can you please give a sample of the data?

Comment: @wwnde thanks for responding! I have edited the post and added sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flag any time you have four consecutive columns with the same value, this list comprehension will work:

```
df['gt 3 consecutive temps'] = [True if i >= 4 else False for i in df['temperature (C)'].groupby((df['temperature (C)'] != df['temperature (C)'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()]

Returns: 
               Datetime    temperature (C)  gt 3 consecutive temps
0   2018-02-04 06:15:00    23               False
1   2018-02-04 06:30:00    20               False
2   2018-02-04 06:45:00    20               False
3   2018-02-04 07:00:00    23               False
4   2018-02-04 07:15:00    26               False
5   2018-02-04 07:30:00    29               False
6   2018-02-04 07:45:00    30               False
7   2018-02-04 08:00:00    30               False
8   2018-02-04 08:15:00    30               True
9   2018-02-04 08:30:00    30               True
10  2018-02-04 08:45:00    30               True
11  2018-02-04 09:00:00    30               True
12  2018-02-04 09:30:00    29               False
13  2018-02-04 09:45:00    30               False
```

If you're only concerned with the hour-over-hour change (start_temp - end_temp <= 0.1), you can use this:

```
df['same_as_one_hour_ago'] = df['temperature (C)'] == df['temperature (C)'].shift(3)

Returns:

               Datetime    temperature (C)  same_as_one_hour_ago
0   2018-02-04 06:15:00    23               False
1   2018-02-04 06:30:00    20               False
2   2018-02-04 06:45:00    20               False
3   2018-02-04 07:00:00    23               False
4   2018-02-04 07:15:00    26               False
5   2018-02-04 07:30:00    29               False
6   2018-02-04 07:45:00    30               False
7   2018-02-04 08:00:00    30               False
8   2018-02-04 08:15:00    30               False
9   2018-02-04 08:30:00    30               True
10  2018-02-04 08:45:00    30               True
11  2018-02-04 09:00:00    30               True
12  2018-02-04 09:30:00    29               False
13  2018-02-04 09:45:00    30               True
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always spaced by 15 minutes, you can use `shift` to identify the rows and `index` to get the indices.

```
thresh = 0.1

# create a boolean flag
df['flag'] = df.temperature - df.temperature.shift(2) < thresh

# print indices
print(df.loc[df.temperature - df.temperature.shift(2) < thresh].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime']) 
# you don't need this: df = df.set_index(['Datetime'])

print(df[df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Datetime', freq='60Min', \
    base=0, label='right'))['temperature(C)'].diff() < 0.1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Coerce Date to dattetime

```
df.Date= pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Set date as index

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Check condition

```
df.groupby(df.index.hour)['temperature '].diff().le(-0.1)
```